# How to refresh ListView when receiving Incoming Messages

Tags: android, listview, sms

I am trying to develop an SMS app in Android. I am not implementing my own broadcastReceiver but using the default in device. Now the problem is I have to call `onResume()` method to show changes in Messages ListView by switching activities. Is there a way to programatically refresh it without reopening my app r switching to other activities(in order to call `onResume()`) to show the received message.
Simply I want my adapter to get refreshed and able to show the received message by adding another row in listView.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand you correctly, but are you asking how you can refresh a `ListView` that isn't visible to the user?

Comment: Look you have opened an activity that contains all the messages.Now while you are in same activity and you receive a new message this listview should get refreshed to show this very new message and i dont know how to do that..AM I clear this time?

Comment: use `notifyDatasetChanged()` on your `Adapter`

Comment: Okay but where should I notify my `Adapter` as it has already recieved a complete list of existing messages? I am sorry if this too dumb but I am confused here..

Answer (score 1):

Calling this will refresh Listview

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Okay but where should I notify my Adapter as it has already recieved a complete list of existing messages? I am sorry if this too dumb but I am confused here..

Comment: why are you all dicking this guy around so much his question is clear. He has a screen , say its a private message thread between 2 users, he loads the data in, but durring that time what happens if the person on the other side replys? how does he update his activity properly?

Answer (score 0):

you must use threads , and your thread will automatically look for any new message. after receiving any message you can refresh your `ListView`

Regards Hayk Nahapetyan

Comment: I haven't work yet in `threads` this much. Can you please elaborate your answer a bit or give me any example so I may able to implement it..

Comment: It's easy. you can thing like this , thread is a program that works under your app , and is doing function that you gave , so you thread can check e.g. every 5 seconds , is there any new message received or not , if yes , than you can do what you want , for thread you can look for some tutorials or for some example, it's easy for understanding ;)

Comment: gives us very little insight into "how" to actually implement this